# How can i reset child dropdown when parent down has been changed?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Here is full demo what i want to say..

when I select android than it gives options of android and when I change option to apple than old option already select how can I unselect them. Any idea ?

[**DEMO**](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-multiple-validation-demo-91vig?file=/src/index.tsx)

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the values of the inner selects in a variables, and reset them when the outer select changes.

```
const [left, setLeft] = useState();
const [right, setRight] = useState();
```

and then, use this values like this:

```
<Select
   placeholder="Minimum OS version"
   options={
      selectedPlatform === "IOS" ? iosVersions : androidVersions
   }
   onChange={(e: any) => setLeft(e)}
   value={left}        
/>
```

and in the onChange of the outer select do:

```
setLeft(null);
setRight(null);
```